# SQL Case statement query

Tags: sql, sql-server, syntax, reporting-services, case-statement

See image.

I have a table full of records relating to specific departments. If the department name is held under the field 'StandardWork' but after the word 'Support -' what is the SQL command to create a new column called Service which will disregard the word support, the space and the dash and just use the department to the right?

[image]

Comment: A permanent column to replace "standardWork"? or co-existing?

Comment: That image is really hard to look at.

Comment: a co-existing colum which is taking the department name from StandardWork

Comment: @SQL_Surfer: why not use a computed column then like I suggested? Your choice of accepted answer doesn't match your stated requirement...

Comment: The answer I accepted worked for me, it kept the original column and also gave me a new one, I wanted to accept all as they all worked but i was only allowed to accept one so I decided on that one as it was the first i tried. Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx)

```
select replace(StandardWork, 'Support - ', '')
```

or [stuff](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx) if you have departments that has `Support -` as a part of the name.

```
select stuff(StandardWork, 1, 10, '')
```

Comment: That will break when StandardWork contains `'Support - something - Support - something else'`

Comment: @FilipDeVos - Break is a bit harsh :). But it will certainly replace **all** instances of `'Support - '` in `StandardWork`. Updated answer with another way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

If `StandardWork` need to exist alongside `Service`, computed column

```
ALTER TABLE Whatever
   ADD [Service] AS SUBSTRING(StandardWork, 11, 8000);
```

If to replace `StandardWork`, then:

```
ALTER TABLE Whatever
   ADD [Service] varchar(200) NULL;

UPDATE Whatever SET [Service] = SUBSTRING(StandardWork, 11, 8000);

ALTER TABLE Whatever
   ALTER COLUMN [Service] varchar(200) NOT NULL;

ALTER TABLE Whatever
   DROP COLUMN StandardWork;
```

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to use the `STUFF` function to solve these issues.

```
    select stuff(StandardWork, 1, 10, '')
```

This function will delete the characters 1-10 and replace them with an empty string.

Comment: Oh. +1 for stuff then :). (Should really be 1, 10.)

Answer (score 1):

Inside a select statement:

```
select ...
       case when StandardWork like 'Support - %' 
            then replace(StandardWork, 'Support - ', '')
       end SupportSubCategory
       ...
```